# python time format check

Tags: python, regex

At python, I want to check if the input string is in "HH:MM" such as 01:16 or 23:16 or 24:00. Giving true or false by the result.

How can I achieve this by using regular expression ?

Comment: Do you want "two digits, colon, two digits" or do you want to check if it's actually a legal time value?

Comment: Strictly speaking '24:00' is not a valid 'HH:MM' string. '00:00' through '23:59' are.

Comment: Midnight is a special case and can be referred to as both "00:00" and "24:00". The notation "00:00" is used at the beginning of a calendar day and is the more frequently used. [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can achieve this without regular expressions:

```
import time

def isTimeFormat(input):
    try:
        time.strptime(input, '%H:%M')
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

>>>isTimeFormat('12:12')
True

>>>isTimeFormat('012:12')
False
```

Comment: `isTimeFormat("12:0")` returns `True`. Not what I want.

Comment: @6infinity8 you could always throw a quick char length check in if you want to be stricter about it `if len(input) != 5: return False`

Comment: can use `datetime.strptime` as well!

Answer (score 7):

```
import re

time_re = re.compile(r'^(([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)|24:00)$')
def is_time_format(s):
    return bool(time_re.match(s))
```

Matches everything from 00:00 to 24:00.

Comment: Thanks, same for 23:59:59 is `time_re = re.compile(r'^(([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)|24:00):([0-5]\d)$')`
`

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the regexp object which will check it. However, depending on who you ask 24:00 might not be a valid time (it's 00:00). But I guess this is easy to modify to suit your needs.

```
import re
regexp = re.compile("(24:00|2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])")
```

Answer (score 3):

This pattern should help you:

http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5