# Check format of string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How do I check if a string coming into a function has the correct format? The correct format is "8:30:00" or "16:00:00"

Something like:

```
string_format = "%h%m%s"

if input_data == string_format:
    do this 
else:
    error
```

Comment: You can do it by regex or one of date utils to parse it for you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322464/python-time-format-check?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  I think this question is so a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python time format check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322464/python-time-format-check)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without using regex. Python has `strptime()` method which parses a string representing a time according to a format. If string cannot be parsed according to format, or if it has excess data after parsing, `ValueError` is raised.

Here is the code:

```
import time

given_time = "10:30:45"
try:
    time.strptime(given_time, '%H:%M:%S')
    print("Correct Format")
except ValueError:
    print("Incorrect Format")
```

Here are its formats:

- %a - abbreviated weekday name
- %A - full weekday name
- %b - abbreviated month name
- %B - full month name
- %c - preferred date and time representation
- %C - century number (the year divided by 100, range 00 to 99)
- %d - day of the month (01 to 31)
- %D - same as %m/%d/%y
- %e - day of the month (1 to 31)
- %g - like %G, but without the century
- %G - 4-digit year corresponding to the ISO week number (see %V).
- %h - same as %b
- %H - hour, using a 24-hour clock (00 to 23)
- %I - hour, using a 12-hour clock (01 to 12)
- %j - day of the year (001 to 366)
- %m - month (01 to 12)
- %M - minute
- %n - newline character
- %p - either am or pm according to the given time value
- %r - time in a.m. and p.m. notation
- %R - time in 24 hour notation
- %S - second
- %t - tab character
- %T - current time, equal to %H:%M:%S
- %u - weekday as a number (1 to 7), Monday=1. Warning: In Sun Solaris Sunday=1
- %U - week number of the current year, starting with the first Sunday as the first day of the first week
- %V - The ISO 8601 week number of the current year (01 to 53), where week 1 is the first week that has at least 4 days in the current year, and with Monday as the first day of the week
- %W - week number of the current year, starting with the first Monday 
  as the first day of the first week
- %w - day of the week as a decimal, Sunday=0
- %x - preferred date representation without the time
- %X - preferred time representation without the date
- %y - year without a century (range 00 to 99)
- %Y - year including the century
- %Z or %z - time zone or name or abbreviation
- %% - a literal % character

Comment: If you need to check many lines, you need to build a high ladder from try-catch blocks. I don't think this is a good pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to match the format, then take action depending on if a match is found. Provide `re.match()` with a pattern and the string you want to check:

```
import re

strings = ["8:30:00", "16:00:00", "845:00", "aa:bb:00"]

for s in strings:
    if re.match("\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}", s):  # Will return True if pattern matches s
        print("match: {}".format(s))  # Take action on a matching pattern
    else:
        print("no match: {}".format(s))
```

The pattern `\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` will match 1 or 2 digits, colon, 2 digits, colon, and 2 digits

The above will print:

```
match: 8:30:00
match: 16:00:00
no match: 845:00
no match: aa:bb:00
```